# How to merge Firebase Realtime Database security rules?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have multiple root nodes and security rules for all those nodes are same as follows

```
".read": "auth.uid == uid"
".write": "auth.uid == uid"
```

Instead of repeating the same code again and again how to merge this following code?

```
{
"rules": {
    "node_1": {
       "$uid": {
           ".read": "auth.uid == uid"
           ".write": "auth.uid == uid"
      }
   },
   "node_2": {
      "$uid": {
          ".read": "auth.uid == uid"
          ".write": "auth.uid == uid"
      }
   },
   "node_3": {
      "$uid": {
          ".read": "auth.uid == uid"
          ".write": "auth.uid == uid"
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

[image]

```
fetchUserProfile = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( Constants.FB_PROFILE_INFO ).orderByKey().equalTo( mAuth.getUid() );
```

Comment: Can you share what data is stored an who do want to give access to?

Comment: Sub nodes of all root nodes are USER ID

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable, just like you are now with $uid:

```
{
"rules": {
  "$node": {
     "$uid": {
       ".read": "auth.uid == $uid"
       ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
     }
  }
}
```

This only make sense if you know, for certain, that all of the top-level nodes have the same structure.  If they don't, you will perhaps need to organize them differently.  There are no partial string matches for names of nodes.

Comment: You need to have a dollar sign in front of $uid as shown in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authorization

Comment: Yes, I had added $uid

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client query that isn't working the way you expect. The query must match the rules.